# Load a laravel view via axios and maintain vue interaction?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a card component with various sub components for interaction. These card components are rendered on a view, let's call it index.

I also have some javascript on my root vue component (infinite scroll) that calls an api via axios that renders the next set of card components, via:

```
return view('pages.cards', ['data' => $data])->render();
```

I've thought about adding these components via [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) but all component interaction is lost.

My question is how can I load in a laravel view via axios and still have the interaction on the components.

Please note, I am rending the views in the API for SEO best practice purposes. So that they are accessible without javascript/infinite scroll.

Comment: Vue was never meant to be used this way. There's no official way of fetching "templates". Generally you preload them all on the first load, along with the whole app and then just fetch the data to populate those templates. There might be a way to do what you need to but probably hacky.

Comment: devk - thanks for the heads up, so I suppose I should have the card component, in a loop and populate it via data loaded by axios, then on infinite scroll, add to the data set and thus add items to the page.

Comment: Yes that's pretty much it. From what I've heard Vue also has server side rendering options. Never tried it with Vue, only with React. And I'm pretty sure you need a Node server to render server-side and also have Vue interactions afterwards. And you'll still need a separate server for API (data only) to populate the templates. Basically, chances are you'll need a lot of refactoring to get SSR to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the information!